# How to preload everything on a webpage using firefox?

Tags: firefox

I am using firefox and I have slow internet. What I want is to be able to open a webpage, leave it there while it preloads everything, then use it super fast. Take for example a website like reddit. I want to open the front page, leave it for like 15 minutes, then come back and be able to instantly see every image/video because it's all preloaded. I am already able to do this to some extend with the firefox addon imagus and reddit enchancement suite. However, those addons won't load videos/gifs/webms and they're are like 50% of the page. I can't google a solution for this and wonder if any of you have an answer here. I am open to a custom coding solution since I can code a bit myself but I'd rather not because it's going to take me like 20hrs to make it work. I don't code all the time and familiarizing myself with it all again takes forever.

To put it succinctly, I want to open reddit's front page, leave it for 15 mins and come back to be able to load any image/webm/gif instantly.

Comment: Try in `about:config` to set `browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand` to `false`. It won't work if the page explicitly specified `preload="none"` and for video it may require changing the HTML using Greasemonkey.